# Workaround for the ScrollViewer flickering in 15063 SDK?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm working on an update for my app using the new 15063 SDK and I've noticed the new default template for the `ScrollViewer` has an annoying flickering when loading some content in a `ListView`, as well as when tapping on an item in a list and navigating to another page.

I haven't changed anything in the lists or in the scroller, as far as these two controls are concerned I've just updated the project to the new SDK and recompiled the app.

Here's a short video that illustrates the issue: [**ScrollViewer glitch**](https://youtu.be/8x_0iariYfE)

You can see that the vertical scroll bar (that has its visibility mode set to Auto) appears and then disappears for a fraction of a second every time I navigate back to the home page and the content is loaded. It's not an issue with the home page: if I navigate to another page and then to the Groups page (for example), the issue will appear in the Groups page as well. it basically appears once every two pages for some reason (and always when loading new content in other pages/controls).

Is there a way to fix this?

So far here's what I came up with:

```
public static void FadeInScrollBarWithDelay([NotNull] this ListView listView, int delay = 800)
{
    if (delay <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The delay must be greater than zero");
    ScrollBar scroller = listView.FindChild<ScrollBar>("VerticalScrollBar");
    if (scroller == null) return;
    scroller.Opacity = 0;
    ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listView, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
    scroller.StartXAMLTransformFadeAnimation(0, 1, 200, delay, EasingFunctionNames.Linear);
}
```

*Note*: that `StartXAMLTransformFadeAnimation` is just a method from [this library](https://github.com/Sergio0694/UICompositionAnimations) that creates and starts a `DoubleAnimation` for the element opacity.

Basically, I set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property in every `ListView` to Hidden, and then call this method that fades the vertical bar back in as soon as the content is loaded. It still doesn't completely fix the issue though, as the vertical scroll bar flickers again if I tap on an item in the list using a touch screen).

I hope I'm not the only one facing this problem with the new SDK, thanks in advance for your help!

---

**Edit**: I attached a `CustomVisualStateManager` to the `ScrollViewer` control and found out that, as expected, when that flickering happens the control is jumping from the `NoIndicator` visual state to the `MouseIndicator` (or `TouchIndicator`) state and back to the `NoIndicator` state instantly, that's why the flickering happens.

This happens every single time I click on an item in a `ListView` control, as well as when the content is loaded inside a `ScrollViewer`.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I was trying to come up with a `VisualStateManager` that uses a timer and a delay to apply the states after a given time threshold in order to be able to skip these "fake" states, but so far it isn't working as expected.

Comment: I see no flickering. where in detail do you see this? update your GPU drivers

Comment: My GPU drivers, really? This is happening both on a clean installed PC and on a phone, clearly it has nothing to do with drivers. Take a look at the video, you can see that every time I navigate to the home page, the scrollbar (on the right) flashes for a moment, it appears as soon as the items are loaded and then disappears immediately.

Comment: Are you able to create a repo for this? This looks like a bug to me. You should probably create a sample repo and raise it at https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues.

Comment: @JustinXL It's happening in basically every single place where I have a ScrollViewer/ListView, so I guess it doesn't depend on a specific item template I'm using or on a specific page layout. I've posted on that repo (thanks for the link), I really hope I'm not the only one with this issue. I'll also create a repo if they say that could help, sure :)

Comment: now I see this small glitch. if you have no idea what you should look for you never notice this.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Trust me, it's much more noticeable on a phone. Besides, it was working perfectly fine before updating the SDK, I find it extremely annoying that the new (supposedly better) template introduced bugs that weren't there before.

Comment: do you have a small demo (github demo repository) that I can compile it on my own and test it on my 950XL?